# How to get the context of the running tests in scala-test ? Is there anything like ITestContext as in TestNG to get those information?

Tags: scala, automated-tests, sbt, testng, scalatest

I want to know the list of running test cases and manipulate with those information. In TestNG, implementing the onFinish, onStart, etc., methods of ITestListener gives ITestContext to retrieve those information. Is there anything similar to that in scala-test. Suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Sky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21860347/926710) is actually looking in the right direction. Mixing in ScalaTest's [BeforeAndAfterAll](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.0/#org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll) trait gives you access to some contextual information about the suite, such as:

- The suite name
- The number of tests in the suite
- The names of tests in the suite
- Tag information for the suite

The information you get is perhaps not as rich as the contextual information you get from TestNG (for example, this trait won't be able to tell you which tests passed/failed in `afterAll`). Maybe however the information it gives you is good enough for your purposes:

```
class MyTest extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll {

    override def beforeAll() {

        // suiteName will give you the name of the suite
        info(suiteName)

        // testNames will give you the names of your tests
        testNames forEach info(_)

        // tags will give you a mapping of test names to tags
        tags.keys.forEach(t => 
            info(t + " tagged with tags " + tags(t).mkString(",")))
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Scalatest has `BeforeAndAfter` trait which has:

```
before{
//write code here(run before each test cases in a test file )
}

after{
// write code here(run after each test cases in a test file )
}
```

and an other trait `BeforeAndAfterAll` which has:

```
override def afterAll: Unit = {
  //write code here(run after all test cases in a test file )
}

override def beforeAll: Unit = {
//write code here(run before all test cases in a test file )
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't get the question correctly. I want to get the context of currently running test suite when I run any test method in scala-test. BeforeAndAfter doesn't give any information about the currently running test cases, as far as I know. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I think there are no context in scalatest but i am not sure.

Comment: Same I too think. Thanks for your reply.